# Domain ignores .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with the domain linked to a folder on my Debian server (with Apache).
(I'll use `domain.com` for the link of my server hosting the files, and `newdomain.com` for the domain name I want to link to it.)

## Facts

The website consists of .html pages. I have this .htaccess in `www.domain.com/subfolder/` for removing the '.html'. The `subfolder`-folder is where I'm hosting the website on my server.
This works perfect for e.g. `www.domain.com/subfolder/photos`

```
  RewriteEngine on

  #example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

  #301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I bought a .be domain name for the website that is hosted on `www.domain.com/subfolder/`, let's call it `newdomain.be`. 
I connected it to the server with a vhost and edited the A-records. (And reloaded Apache, ..)

```
  <virtualhost *:80>

        # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
        ServerAdmin webmaster@newdomain.be
        ServerName  newdomain.be
        ServerAlias www.newdomain.be
 
 
        # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subfolder
 
  </virtualhost>
```

## Problem

The DNS-settings are okay, `www.newdomain.be` works and shows the index.html from my `domain.com/subfolder/`. 
But, `www.newdomain.be/photos` throws a 404! Note that `www.newdomain.be/photos.html` works as expected, so the problem must be in the Rewriting I guess... 
Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: When I insert errors in the .htaccess file, the domain.com/subfolder throws an error, but the newdomain.be still works. So it's clear that the newdomain.be ignores the .htaccess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay guys, I was finally able to fix it!

Apparently adding a few extra lines in the VirtualHost did the trick :-)

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/subfolder
<Directory /var/www/subfolder>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the file permissions for the new folder ?

try chmod -R command for the /var/www/subfolder/

Comment: File permissions look right, folder and .htaccess file are both set to R(eadable) for everyone...